# SqlCommandBuilder cannot handle SQLDataAdapter with Multiple SQL-Statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, dataset

I'm working on a simple userclient (frontend) for a MS SQL Server database.

The database itself is pretty straight forward, there are eight tables without any foreign keys.

So far I managed to connect to the database and load all tables and data into a dataset.
I'm doing this by using a single string with multiple SQL-Statements (one for each table):

```
 _dbconstrb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
 _dbconstrb.DataSource = ".\local";
 _dbconstrb.InitialCatalog = "mydatabase";


string sql_str = "SELECT * FROM tbl1; SELECT * FROM tbl2; ..."
_dbda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_str, _sqlcon);
_dbds = new DataSet();
_dbda.Fill(_dbds);
```

The dataset is bind to a `bindingsource` and this is set as datasource for a `DataGridView`. I'm using a simple `ComboBox`, where the user can select one of the eight database tables. Everytime the user makes any change on the combobox, the datamember of the bindingsource is set to selected table from the combobox. So far it works perfect.
Now the user will make any changes in the gridview data (add, delete or change records).
I would like to update the database by using the SQLCommandBulider and I tried this:

```
SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(_dbda);
int updated = _dbda.Update(_dbds);
```

However this only works on the data of the first table (the table which comes first in the sql-string, in this case it is tbl1). It seems that all followed tables are not recognized by the DataAdapter. Do I really have to use eight DataAdapters (one for each table) to achieve this?

Solution:
Finally I managed this by adding eight `DataApter`. However, the `Entity Framework` looks very promising for such kind of datahandling. Again thanx for that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although your application might be simple not sure if loading the data from all the tables is good idea in terms of performance. I think using entity framework will help you http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/working-with-data-(entity-framework-tutorial) 
and its really simple for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its not asp.net :) just that the tutorial happens to be under asp.net :)

Comment: oh, sorry. Looks really intresting...thanx for that info.